# How to transfer custom class object to another module , and initialise it?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, eval

I am currently working on some code to read audio data and change it, and that same data to be displayed in `tkinter gui` in real time.

Basic functionality i would like to have is this (in pseudo code):

From audio reader

```py
#audio_data_reader.py
AudioData = AudioDataFrom( "wave.wav" );
SendADto( "wave_show_gui.py", repr(AudioData) ); 

#do some Audio Data manipulation  

Refresh( "wave_show_gui.py", AudioData );
```

To audio gui:

```py
#wave_show_gui.py
audio_data_repr_string = Get_Audio_Data( "audio_data_reader.py" );
AudioData = dePhrase( audio_data_repr_string );

self.tk.show_data(AudioData);
```

I want to do this since i know how waveform my sound library is supposed to look like ( using my Digital Audio Workstation ) but i am not sure if i am decompressing it right.

To make things easier i've made an `base_class` with some default "`virtual`" functions that every class inherits from then on. Among those functions is an custom `__repr__` function that governs the way i represent data in string form so i can have consistent representation along the way for each class.

Transfer among `wave_show_gui.py` and `audio_data_reader.py` is done via TCP/IP socket server/client, and data is stored not as a audio bytes but as generator function. So instead of list of bytes, i have `1 A 30Hz 2secs,4 A 40Hz 1 secs, 2A 1323 Hz + 32 theta 5 secs :overall 60 s` etc. So receiver can recalculate that sound and generate it on the fly via pythons `generators`.

The problem i am having is that even if same libraries are imported in both python files, when i successfully transfer data to `wave_show_gui.py` i get:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SPA.py", line 88, in <module>
    print( dePhrase( testPhrased ) ) #? raises error, eval, TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
  File "G:\SPACEPOS\bin\LIB\__init__.py", line 76, in dePhrase
    x = eval(x)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```